# How can i remove a transparent background from a .png image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I try to remove the transparent background of a .png image and then scaling it to the seeable content of the image.

Comment: Look into opencv, but that's not how you ask a question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `A` from an `RGBA` image, just use:

```
RGBimage = RGBAimage.convert('RGB')
```

To trim the image, use `Image.getbbox()`. Documentation [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html).